# Deleting rows from mysql that older than 1 minute

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySQL database in LAMP server, Database is called coe and table is called pulses. the columns are:

Pulse |    int

id    |    int

time  |    timestamp - current timestamp

I want select all values in pulse and then choose the max value with last 1 minute from current time. After that, I want to delete all rows in table with also last 1 minute.

I tried this code:

```
<?php 

$servername = "localhost"; 
$username = "root";  
$password = "";
$dbname = "testdb";

$mysqli = mysqli_connect ($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT MAX(pulse) as pulse FROM pulses where pulse BETWEEN 400 and 500 AND time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 60");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
echo $row['pulse'];
$DeleteQuery = mysql_query('DELETE FROM pulses WHERE time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 60)');
?>
```

The code section of connection with database and select data with max value that work and it is not deleting the rows. i tried a lot but without success. please help

Comment: Surely if you want "older than", then you should be using `<`

Comment: Did you notice your `$DeleteQuery` is set to `mysql_query()`

Comment: If you were bothering to look at your error log. It would have been blatently OBVIOUS what the issue was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `mysql_query` instead of `mysqli_query`, check syntax.
Like Barry Thomas said, change your `>` operator to `<`

Comment: He is also using the incorrect operator in the query, he has > should be <. If you wan to update your answer to include.

Comment: Thanks i changed into `mysqli_query` and the operator to `<` but also does not work the error is now `mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters` on line `DELETE FROM pulses WHERE time < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 60`

Comment: add ($mysqli, before "Delete... See the first query